# Monkey patch Rails UniquenessValidator to support conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, monkeypatching

In my Rails 3.2.11 application I need the uniqueness validator to support conditions, in order to ignore soft deleted records. On GitHub I found a pull request doing that (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5321) but this feature seems not to be part of the current Rails release. Now I created a patch for the UniquenessValidator class, which looks like this:

```
module UniquenessValidatorExtension
  def build_relation(klass, table, attribute, value)
    relation = super
    relation.merge!(options[:conditions]) if options[:conditions]
    relation
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator.send :include, UniquenessValidatorExtension
```

To load this, I created an initializer. The problem is, that my method is never called. What do I do wrong?

Here is the link to the current UniquenessValidator class: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0d73d6e7b6dd1900f105397460b777ef6c03d3b6/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb

Answer (score 1):

That's how `include` works:

```
module M; end

class C
  include M
end

C.ancestors # => [C, M, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

so in your case method `build_relation` from the original class will be called. JFYI, there `prepend` method in Ruby 2.0:

```
class C1
  prepend M
end

C1.ancestors # => [M, C1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

so in your case method `build_relation` will be called from the module.

Well, right now you can reopen `UniquenessValidator` and override your whole `build_relation` method

Comment: That was exactly the problem. But since I use Ruby 1.9.x, `prepend` is not a solution for me. I found another way to do that and I'll explain that in another answer from me in this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the method is never called, that means that you've included your module AFTER ActiveRecord::Base 'required' it. Try to include it before:

```
config.before_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator.send :include, UniquenessValidatorExtension
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was explained by @nash, but since I use Ruby 1.9.x, this is not a solution. To get it work, I aliased the original method and then replaced it. Now I was able to call the aliased method from the overwriting one.

```
class ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  alias_method :build_relation_orig, :build_relation
  def build_relation(klass, table, attribute, value)
    relation = self.build_relation_orig(klass, table, attribute, value)
    relation = relation.and(options[:conditions]) if options[:conditions]
    relation
  end
end
```